# RabbitMQ PHP Consumer Database Connection

Tags: php, database, rabbitmq, database-connection, daemon

I am considering using RabbitMQ for some async processing in my new app.

One of the challenges I am facing is how best to handle Database connections. I will be using Eloquent and in effect PDO.

One resource I found online here https://www.teqneers.de/2013/10/simple-spawn-rabbitmq-consumers-with-php/ suggests spawning a new process using `proc_open` but I am not really comfortable with this approach and wonder if there is a better approach.

I also tried looking best practices for handling a database connection in a PHP daemon but didn't find anything.

Some things I have thought about.

1. **Creating a new connection and closing it per message**

   - Cons: App is about delivering messages to bulk messages and consumers will be numerous and run often. Might be resource heavy.
   - Pros: However, traditional php scripts work in a similar way so this might not be such a bad idea
2. **Keeping the connection throughout the lifetime of the consumer and killing them often**

   - Cons: Obviously wasteful. Need to constantly check if the connection is still active.
3. **Running a worker on the command line**

   - Cons: Too many moving parts. Need to parse the response for message ACKS hence the consumer needs to wait for the worker to end. Means creating and closing connections per message, might as well stick with option 1 as it has less parts.

I also thought of persistent connections, but after reading more about them, it seems they are not what I thought they were. Also, many posts say it is a bad idea anyway.

I understand PHP might not be the best job for this, but I am rapidly prototyping and PHP is the language I am most comfortable in for this task.

I would really appreciate it if I could get some advice on how to handle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to go with a solution that is a merge of the `proc_open` (without actually using `proc_open`) and options 1 and 2.

Using https://github.com/ricbra/rabbitmq-cli-consumer, this cli tool handles the actual consumption of the messages and passes it on to the PHP script via the command line (works as a proxy).

The PHP script is run once per message and returns depending on the exit code (0: successful, 1: failure), the message ACK is handled.

The script runs like a normal PHP script on the CLI so you get to keep your thoughts about resource handling sane. No daemon here.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same problem. Thanks for sharing the above link, seems like a pretty nice way to do this task. Have you found some better advice in the meantime or did you stick to that approach? @frostymarvelous

Comment: I stuck with this. I'm mostly doing dot net now so I haven't had the need to revisit.